# SQL Server Database Project Script Customization w/ Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using a SQL Server Database Project with Visual Studio 2017 and trying to customize the script output to do a couple of things:

1. Create a T-SQL-only script without SQLCMD variables. The person running the script doesn't allow SQLCMD at all. Is it possible to do this?
2. Exclude `GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::[dbo]` and `GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[dbo]` statements. In my situation, these
   statements are specific to a lower environment and should not be deployed to upper environments.

For #1, I've looked around Visual Studio and haven't found any way to do this yet.

For #2, I've tried changing some of the options in schema compare, but somehow the **`GRANT ALTER`** and **`GRANT CONTROL`** statements always appear in the script output and I have to manually delete them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [publishing profile](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9007/define-a-publish-profile-for-ssdt/) as a part of your database project and exclude the parts you don't want to deploy. For example, users, permissions and role memberships can be excluded from deployment.

Then again, it is strange that these statements appear at all. Do you have users and / or logins in your database project? I, for instance, never put them there in the first place, because they are instance-specific and cause more harm than good when you have multiple environments (which is pretty much always the case).

Regarding SQLCMD variables, I don't think you can avoid them completely. The person that receives your script will have to comment them out and replace them with actual values in the code. There must be something remarkably unusual in the way your company has set up the change management in general and change deployment in particular. Maybe you will be able to make them reconsider their olden ways in favour of a more modern approach?..

Comment: For SQLCMD, it's unlikely that will change. The deployment team is pretty adamant about having T-SQL only scripts, so it sounds like I need to manually edit the script before each push.

Comment: @user2966445, I'm not an expert in the subject, but as I understand it should be possible to concoct some kind of regular expression which will do the job for you. That is, replacing the placeholders and commenting out their definitions. Try and see if you can :)

Comment: When would the replacement happen though?

Comment: @user2966445, there is a post-build event handler in project properties, but I don't think it will trigger after publish script generation. Apart from that, I can't think of anything available out of the box. Write a script or a console program and set it to watch the output directory for files to appear that match the `*.publish.sql` pattern? Or maybe shopping around might help.